Next.js 14: why is revalidateTag acting as a full refresh the first time its run?
I'm mutating data from a client component via server action, and then refetching the data via revalidateTag.
I'm seeing that on the first revalidation after a page is rendered, all client state is reset - so its effectively acting as a full refresh. But then subsequent revalidation works as expected - i.e. data is refetched server-side and updated, but unrelated client state is maintained.
I've created a simplified test and am seeing the same results with router.refresh, revalidateTag, and revalidatePath.
In my test application, page.tsx fetches and displays some data, while its child client component renders a form to mutate that data via server action. The server action then revalidates via revalidateTag. The client component also displays a counter for visibility of client state.
To test, I increment the counter and then submit the form. On the first submittal, the data is revalidated but the counter is reset to 0. Subsequent revalidation works and does not reset the counter.
The documentation I've seen says that revalidateTag should re-render the server component and then essentially merge the new data into any existing state, leaving any unrelated client state unchanged...right? I don't understand why that is only not the case on the first revalidation.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!!
//// app/test/page.tsx ////

import { API_MACHINE_GET_DETAILS } from "../api/azure/Machines/apiRoutes";
import { MachineDetails } from "../utils/interfaces";
import Client from "./client";


export default async function Page() {
    const id = '13502294-e057-4001-ac3f-3cc0132742b4';
    const url = `${API_MACHINE_GET_DETAILS}?id=${id}`

    // fetch and display data
    const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'GET',
        cache: 'no-cache'
    });
    const jsonData = await response.json();
    const machineDetails: MachineDetails = jsonData;

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{machineDetails.displayName}</h1>
            <Client />
        </div>
    );
}

//// app/test/client.tsx ////

'use client';

import { useState } from "react";
import { updateMachine } from "../actions/apiUtils";

export default function Client() {
    // client side state which should not be reset
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);

    return (
        <div style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: 'column' }}>
            <p>client state: {counter}</p>
            <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter + 1)}>Increment</button>
            <form action={updateMachine}>
                <input type="text" name="displayName" />
                <button type="submit">Update Machine</button>
            </form>
        </div >
    );
}

'use server';

import { ApiResponse } from "@/app/utils/interfaces";
import { revalidateTag } from "next/cache";
import { API_MACHINE_UPDATE } from "../api/azure/Machines/apiRoutes";

const API_ERROR_MESSAGE = 'Error sending request. Please notify your administrator for assistance.';

async function updateMachine(formData: FormData): Promise<ApiResponse> {
    'use server';

    formData.append('id', '13502294-e057-4001-ac3f-3cc0132742b4');
    formData.append('machineNumber', '1234');

    try {
        const response = await fetch(API_MACHINE_UPDATE, {
            method: 'PUT',
            body: formData,
        });
        const jsonData = await response.json();
        if (response.ok) {
            revalidateTag('api'); // revalidation
            return { status: response.status, message: jsonData.message };
        }
        return { status: response.status, message: jsonData.message || API_ERROR_MESSAGE };
    } catch (error) {
        return { status: 500, message: API_ERROR_MESSAGE };
    }
}

export { updateMachine };


UPDATE: got it working
I discovered that the source of this behavior was that I had a loading.tsx file at the root of my app directory. I'm not exactly sure how/why this created the described behavior, but it did.
I had put this in place a while back per the documentation: https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/loading-ui-and-streaming
I guess you are only supposed to use this convention in route segments, but not the root page/layout. It would have been helpful to specify that in the documentation, or maybe its a bug?

Removing the root loading.tsx solved this issue for me to. Thank you so much Iain!
